# Div is not responsive, text overlay div

Tags: html, css

As you can see, here I have a FAQ section, but when I click on one of the quesiton it not working correclty the text `Frequently Asked Question` does not expend to the top

[image]

[image]

here is my code:

```css
.Frequently {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(103, 58, 183), rgb(81, 45, 168));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* FAQ SECTION */

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.accordion-item {
  background-color: #0b0b18;
  ;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: .5rem 2px .5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.accordion-link {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  text-decoration: none!important;
  background-color: #0b0b18;
  ;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.accordion-link ion-icon {
  color: #e7d5ff;
  padding: .5rem;
}

ion-icon[name="remove"] {
  display: none;
}

.answer {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(81, 45, 168);
  transition: max-height 650ms;
}

.answer::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: .6rem;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #8fc460;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.answer p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .answer {
  max-height: 20rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link ion-icon[name="add"] {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link ion-icon[name="remove"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="col-12" align="center">
    <h1 class="Frequently">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item" id="question1">
          <a class="accordion-link" href="#question1">
            How often do you go to beach?
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
          </a>
          <div class="answer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores consequuntur deleniti dignissimos, dolore enim error facere illum magni maiores quae, quam voluptates. Impedit maiores mollitia nam obcaecati rerum sequi velit?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<section>` using `height: 100vh;` and `<h1>` using `position: relative;` that why they are overlay together.

Here I'm removing `height: 100vh;` from `<section>` to make the section height match with content height and don't overlay the element above. For other approaches you want, you could adjust based on the core issue that I point out above.

```css
.Frequently {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(103, 58, 183), rgb(81, 45, 168));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* FAQ SECTION */
section {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.container1 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.accordion-item {
    background-color: #0b0b18;;
    border-radius:  .4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    box-shadow: .5rem 2px .5rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.accordion-link {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    text-decoration: none!important;
    background-color: #0b0b18;;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}

.accordion-link ion-icon{
    color: #e7d5ff;
    padding: .5rem;
}

ion-icon[name="remove"] {
    display: none;
}

.answer {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(81, 45, 168);
    transition: max-height 650ms;
}

.answer::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: .6rem;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #8fc460;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.answer p {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .answer {
    max-height: 20rem;

}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link ion-icon[name="add"] {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link ion-icon[name="remove"] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="col-12" align="center">
        <h1 class="Frequently">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
    </div>
    <section>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-item" id="question1">
                    <a class="accordion-link" href="#question1">
                        How often do you go to beach?
                        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
                    </a>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores consequuntur deleniti dignissimos, dolore enim error facere illum magni maiores quae, quam voluptates. Impedit maiores mollitia nam obcaecati rerum sequi velit?
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

More information about: [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#:%7E:text=the%20default%20value.-,relative,-The%20element%20is) and [vh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#:%7E:text=the%20viewport%27s%20width.-,vh,-1%25%20of%20the) or easier docs [vh w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it-,vh,-Relative%20to%201) and [relative w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,position%3A%20relative%3B,-An%20element%20with).

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .Frequently {
   
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(103, 58, 183), rgb(81, 45, 168));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}


/* FAQ SECTION */


section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.container1 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.accordion-item {
    background-color: #0b0b18;
    border-radius:  .4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;

    padding: 1rem;
    box-shadow: .5rem 2px .5rem rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.accordion-link {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    text-decoration: none!important;
    background-color: #0b0b18;;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 0;
}

.accordion-link ion-icon{
    color: #e7d5ff;
    padding: .5rem;
}


ion-icon[name="remove"] {
    display: none;
}

.answer {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(81, 45, 168);
    transition: max-height 650ms;
}

.answer::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: .6rem;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #8fc460;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.answer p {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .answer {
    max-height: 20rem;

}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link ion-icon[name="add"] {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link ion-icon[name="remove"] {
    display: block;
}
.accordion {
  background-color: #0b0b18;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-12">
  <section>
      <div class="container1">
          <div class="accordion">
            <div class="col-12" align="center">
              <h1 class="Frequently">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
          </div>
              <div class="accordion-item" id="question1">
                  <a class="accordion-link" href="#question1">
                      How often do you go to beach?
                      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
                      <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
                  </a>
                  <div class="answer">
                      <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores consequuntur deleniti dignissimos, dolore enim error facere illum magni maiores quae, quam voluptates. Impedit maiores mollitia nam obcaecati rerum sequi velit?

                      </p>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  </div>
```

is this what you are looking for?